# Word 2010 .docm, add in automatically

Tags: vba, ms-word, add-in, word-2010

I have created a .docm file.  I want to have it "add-in" automatically every time I open Word 2010.

I have added it to Windows 7 at the following location...

C:\Users\Donald\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Word\STARTUP

I have added it to Windows XP machine at the following locations...

C:\Documents and Settings\Donald Adams\Application Data\Microsoft\Word\STARTUP

It works fine if I manually add the .docm file but does not automatically "add-in" based on its location.

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was open the .docm file in Word and "Save As" a .dotm file, then move the .dotm file to the folders.  It now loads automatically.